# Symfony -- Sort child records in oneToMany relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this entry for Entity Route. 
I want to sort entitiy list trplist on another field, but by default the sorting is done on id.

What is configuration change I need to make?

oneToMany:
    trplist:
      targetEntity: TravelRoutePoints
      mappedBy: route
      cascade: ["persist", "remove"]
           joinColumn:
        name: id
        referencedColumnName: tr_id

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess the dostrine OrderBy annotation is what you're looking for:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $groups;
```

see docs: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#orderby

So, your relation in yaml format should look like:

```
oneToMany:
    trplist:
        targetEntity: TravelRoutePoints
        mappedBy: route
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"] 
        joinColumn: 
            name: id 
            referencedColumnName: tr_id
        orderBy:
            anotherFieldName: DESC
```

Comment: I am using yml for configuration, whats the syntax for order by there?